# Custom login page episerver

Tags: episerver

So I am trying to create a custom login page instead of the EPi Server. Right now I have created a custom controller and model and page using this tutoiral

https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Daniel-Ovaska/Dates/2016/6/creating-a-custom-login-page/

The thing is when I type http://localhost:53067/LoginPage/Index in the browser window I get null for the currenPage in the below code

```
    public ActionResult Index(LoginPage currentPage, [FromUri]string ReturnUrl)
    {
        /* Implementation of action. You can create your own view model class that you pass to the view or
         * you can pass the page type for simpler templates */


        var model = new LoginModel(currentPage);
        model.LoginPostbackData.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please post the entire code for the `LoginPageController `

Comment: @Chaudhry Were you helped by the answer below? If so, feel free to mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `currentPage` parameter will only have a value if there is a page of type `LoginPage` which maps to the URL.

It seems you're simply browsing to the controller route.

If you create a page of type `LoginPage` called "My login page", it should get a URL like  http://localhost:53067/my-login-page.

If you then browse to that URL, your `Index` method will be invoked, assuming your controller inherits `PageController`.